# Display name and NavigationBarTitle shown Mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, swiftui, mac-catalyst

Is there a way to merge the title bar and the navigation bar for Mac Catalyst apps?

I already tried using the `.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())`. Apparently, it only works for native Mac apps and not for the Mac Catalyst.

Screenshot of the App

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the navigationbar, by setting `navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false` and adding an NSToolbar to the title bar of the window scene in the method `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` of the scene delegate. See an [example here](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/mac-catalyst/adding-a-toolbar).